# Custom Function gives error if rows are removed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom formula to sum all cells in a table with a particular BackColor (thanks StackOverflow!)

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

This is inserted in the **TotalsRowRange** of an Excel Table.

I have created a couple of custom buttons to add new rows and delete rows for each employee in the table, each one has 3 rows with hours, percentages and wages formulas.

If I add new rows, the **SumByColor** function works perfectly and the newly created rows are automatically included in the sum (it sums the lighter green rows).

But when I delete rows, the **SumByColor** function doesn't update correclty and gives a "VALUE" error.
A simple double clikc and OK on the cell resets the formula to normal operation.
I have tried the Calculate method on the TotalsRowRange object, no luck.

[image: Here's the error after deleting rows]

[image: Here's the formula, GENDIR is the name of the column]

Comment: [Application.Volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)?

Comment: seems to work...it seems to slow down the insert of new rows (it's something the customer won't do every day...) ..I simply need to recalculate the totals

Comment: One solution could be to update the formula in the code when you add rows, instead of using a user formula.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I need to add 3 rows for each employee (working hours, percentage of hours, total amount) divided in +/- 40 columns (cost centres, they can change as well from sheet to sheet), so columns are not fixed...

I would need to cycle every time all columns and re-write the formulas in the last rows...

so far your solution is working quite well ;-)

Comment: I didn't know about Application.Volatile...thanks

Comment: @Antonio What about adding a part of code that recalculates your worksheet to the "remove row button"? You can use `.Calculate` to achieve this. Either `Worksheets("name").Calculate` to recalculate the entire worksheet or `Worksheets("name").Rows(2).Calculate` to recalculate specific rows.

Comment: @DirtyDeffy that's exaclty what I did, but it didn't work without the Application.Volatile specified in the custom function...